# Mascara no ionic

Tags: html, typescript, ionic3

Bom dia pessoal, queria uma ajuda, no ion-input do ionic, gostaria de utilizar mascara, de numero de celular e cpf por exemplo, poderiam me ajudar com um exemplo bem simples, utilizo o ionic 3 e angular 4

Comment: o que você ja tentou fazer? qual é a sua dificuldade?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues tentei utilizar o angular2-text-mask e o ionic-text-mask, mas nao tive sucesso em nenhum dos dois

Comment: O que aconteceu?

Comment: eles nao funcionaram na hora de inserir os dados, talvez eu tenha feito algo errado

Comment: ai queria um exemplo bem basico para poder resolver

Comment: ocorreu alguma mensagem de erro? você poderia simular? tem um site que permite você criar demonstrações usando ionic da uma olhada: https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: obrigado, vou testar la